# How can time be curved?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, mass, time-dilation

Time isn't a physical object, but according to Einstein's theory of gravity, mass bends spacetime towards things with mass and makes them fall. How does a physical object affect something intangible?

Comment: This video by ScienceClic improves the usual rubber sheet visualization - [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To be precise, time is not *curved*, it is the spacetime manifold that has curvature. Such a manifold can be given a coordinate chart - an arbitrary one - that assignes to different points (spacetime events) some labels.

It turns out that we need one time coordinate to label the time *slices* and three spatial coordinates to distinguish the events within that *slice*.

What you might satisfactorily say is that the rate of flow of the proper time - the time that your own clock shows - depends on how much spacetime curvature is in your vicinity. This is a quantity independent of any coordinates, a **true** physical property if you will. This proper time is a measure of your aging, biological processes in your organism, the oscillatory frequencies in atomic transition in the atomic clock you might have etc.

Imagine you and your friend orbiting a static black hole. You get the same clocks and synchronize them. They show the same time and tick at the same rate.

Then your friend stays at his orbit (at a distance $r_{friend}$) and you go much closer to the black hole (at a distance $r_{you}$).
You spend some time there and upon returning, you make a discovery that your clocks show different readings!

In fact, using the Schwarzschild solution you could predict that your clocks will exhibit a ratio of proper times that have passed equal to

$$ \frac{\tau_{you}}{\tau_{friend}} = \frac{1-2M/r_{you}}{1-2M/r_{friend}}$$

In the above, I omit the problem of determining when you start and stop the readings and how you account for the travel back and forth. It does not change the fact that your clock will exhibit fewer ticks-and-tocks when you compare it with the one of your friend.

Comment: Really nice answer. I think it is worth mentioning the link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation

Answer (score 11):

If you think about it,  "space" is no more tangible a concept than "time" is.  If one can curve, so can the other.

Spacetime is curved in the same sense that the surface of the Earth is curved.   Two ships sailing on initially parallel paths may nevertheless converge and meet.

An similar example of time curvature is, if someone on a high altitude point, like the Red Bull guy, flashed a laser pulse down at the ground, and then flashed one again 1 second later (by his clock), the pulses would arrive on a detector on the ground less than 1 second apart by our clock. Less by roughly $10^{-12} \,\rm{sec}$.  So the time interval between the two pulse events decreases as we approach the center of the Earth, just as the space interval between the ships decreases as they approach the North Pole.

If it were a black hole instead of the Earth, the pulses could go a lot deeper into the gravity well, and the time between them would approach zero.

Answer (score 5):

In a general sense, time is just a dimension. We could draw a diagram where we say an object curves in space over time. But we could also flip the diagram and say the object curves in time over space. It's just a matter of perspective.

[image: Two graphs, one with fixed time intervals, the next with fixed spatial intervals.]

I think a better way to think of the "curvature" of spacetime is to think of its density changing. Spatial density pushes objects from high density to low density (gravity). Time density tells us things tick at a different rate relative to the "universal clock". Lower temporal density means fewer ticks update an object in the same span of "real" time than an area with higher density.

Of course, "real time" is a hard thing to pin down, and some would argue it's meaningless. But I've always found it easier to acknowledge that there's some relativity to reference frames than to try completely removing them from conversation.

Comment: "Real" (proper) time is what a clock measures. Other notions of time are arbitrary constructions.

Comment: @JohnDoty: But different clocks measure different things. Meaning all notions are arbitrary constructions. "Real" time, in this case, is the notion that one clock is more correct than another. In GR, this is pretty simple: the clock least affected by gravity. In SR, it's less simple since, without actual FTL or something, there's no way to say which clock is "less affected by speed".

Comment: *Coordinate* time is an arbitrary construction. But physics is founded on measurement. Proper time isn't arbitrary: it's what a clock measures. "Least affected by gravity" is perhaps a convenient intention for your arbitrary coordinate time, but it's treacherous. Do you know what a tricky construction TDB is?

Comment: @JohnDoty: Proper time is arbitrary, because you have to pick a clock for it to matter, and you can only properly measure events occurring at that clock. And "least affected by gravity" is actually fundamental to the definition of proper time, because you have to measure a clock in an inertial reference frame for it to truly be a measure of proper time. Note that TDB also includes SR, and is therefore based on an arbitrary reference frame. Hence why I said "real time" is hard to pin down.

Comment: And if it's confusing you, "real" time and "proper" time are not the same thing. "Proper" time is the measure of a clock in specific technical settings. "Real" time is an arbitrary idea defined in my answer, referring to the notion there's a preferred frame of reference from which everything else can be measured. Real time is thus undefined at this point, and may be undefinable. Or it may be critical to understanding time if we find that FTL is possible.

Comment: You don't understand. Proper time is most certainly measurable in an accelerated frame. We do it! Almost all real clocks sit on the Earth's surface, an accelerated frame. You seem to want to rewrite physics. The idea that there cannot be a preferred frame of reference has profound consequences, and we observe them in reality.

Comment: @JohnDoty: You can read a clock. That's not proper time. Proper time is time measured on a clock in an inertial reference frame: it's the definition. Inertial reference frames don't exist in practice. Therefore no actual clock measurements are measurements of proper time, only approximations. And there can absolutely be a preferred frame of reference with zero conflicts with actual observations. It's just that current observations don't give us any ability to determine which real frame is "the frame".

Comment: Sorry, that's not physics. I suggest you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time. You might also cogitate on the famous twin paradox, where the proper time differs depending on trajectory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox

Comment: @JohnDoty: The article you linked agrees with me. It says the clock must follow a "timelike world line". That means it's not moving according to some frame of reference. If it's not moving, it can't be accelerating. I.e., it must be measured in an inertial reference frame. Checking a number of other sources on a quick Google search shows many others agreeing with this definition. I'm not sure where you're hearing otherwise. And the twin paradox, again, simply illustrates my point: "real time" is difficult to pin down.

Comment: Regardless of how you define it, at no point did I actually mention proper time in my answer, so the definition isn't actually relevant.

Comment: You don't understand what a timelike world line is. You, sitting in your chair, are experiencing a timelike world line in an accelerating frame of reference. You want some sort of Platonic absolute time. That's not physics. Physics is based on what you can measure. A mechanism that can measure time is called a clock. Proper time is *by definition* what a clock measures. Reasoning based on this idea makes numerous predictions that conform to reality.

Comment: @JohnDoty: Presume every resource I can find is wrong and you, some random on the internet, are right. So what? You're simply saying the definition of proper time is what a clock says in any reference frame, not just inertial frames. It's a semantic argument about a term I never used to describe a concept I didn't mention. We're not talking about physics, but about words. Yes, there's a difference between what we measure and what we model. But both are part of physics: if you don't model the system, you can't make the predictions that make physics a useful branch of learning.

Comment: Nothing about absolute time is inherently wrong. Relativistic physics is rooted in the concept, and every experiment done to date agrees with it. If we could somehow prove the concept wrong, we'd unravel physics as we know it. The issue is that we can't prove it right, and we can't point to the reference frame in which a clock measures absolute time (in SR, that is; in GR it's trivial). Starting an SR class in "how dare you mention the concept of preferred frames, you heathen!" causes tons of confusion. I have seen it repeatedly. Getting to it by Occam's Razor is much better, in my experience.

Comment: Anyhow, I'm not sure what else I can say except that maybe you could go take some actual classes in physics and philosophy. You seem to be interested in the concepts and have done some preliminary research on them. But you're confused by some basic concepts. Maybe you had a bad teacher, and you just need to revisit those concepts. Either way, I've said what I can about an off-topic issue, so take care.

Comment: I'm a professional physicist. Everything I say is mainstream physics, verified by experiment.

Answer (score 1):

> How does a physical object affect something intangible?

This is actually quite common, not only for the gravitational field,
but also for other fields.

Take for example the electromagnetic field.
This field carries not only energy (as everyone knows from sunlight),
but also momentum and angular momentum.
Hence you should think of the field not as intangible,
but more as a real physical object.
Electric charges make an electromagnetic field.
And the electromagnetic field affects the movement of charged bodies.

> Time isn't a physical object,

More precisely you should talk about spacetime instead of time,
because space and time are closely intertwined.
The same way of thinking like above for the electromagnetic field
applies for the gravitational field
(or for spacetime curvature, by Einstein's language).
Thus spacetime should be considered a real physical object.
Masses curve spacetime.
And curved spacetime affects the movement of masses.

In a sense you can think of spacetime as a very hard stuff,
because you need enormous masses to make only
a tiny curvature of spacetime.
For example: at the surface of the earth the gravity
acceleration is $g=9.8$ m/s$^2$. According to Einstein
this corresponds to a tiny curvature of spacetime.
Its curvature radius is actually $r=\frac{c^2}{g} = 9.2\cdot 10^{15}$ m.