# Can someone really explain the curvature of Spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

I can understand the curvature of a sheet which is 2D but i can't understand the 3D curvature of space described in General Relativity. How's really the curvature of space described in GR? Could someone explain how this curvature affect an object "moving in time" or just moving in space?

Comment: I posted an answer here that may be helpful to you
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/666294/313823

Comment: This is a very good visualization https://youtu.be/wrwgIjBUYVc

Comment: See my [post here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/522440) as well.

Comment: One can imagine that gravitation is the act of the assimilation of processes, where the assimilation strength is based on the gravitational time dilation (which gets stronger the closer one is to the gravitating body). As you fall toward a black hole, you become assimilated. Supposedly, at the event horizon, the assimilation is complete; one becomes blackholeium, and then eventually Hawking radiation, until there is nothing left of the black hole.

Answer (score 8):

Before picturing curved spacetime, start with Newton’s laws in the absence of gravity. Newton’s first law says that an isolated object travels in a straight line at constant speed. If you plot the object’s path in spacetime it forms a straight line, called a worldline. An isolated object can be measured as one where an attached accelerometer reads 0. So basically, Newton’s first law says that an object with an accelerometer reading of 0 forms a straight line in spacetime.

If a pair of objects are at rest with respect to each other then their world lines are parallel. Since both worldlines are straight (accelerometers read 0) and parallel the distance remains constant and they never intersect (collide).

Now, let’s add gravity. Here, objects in free fall still have accelerometers that read 0, so an object in free fall has a straight worldline. But now, two free falling objects that are initially at rest with respect to each other (parallel worldlines) can eventually free fall until they approach each other. In flat spacetime this is impossible, worldlines that are straight and initially parallel cannot change their distance, but in curved spacetimes this is possible, just like two neighboring longitude lines are “straight” and at the equator are parallel but they intersect at the poles.

So curved spacetime is just a generalization that allows us to use geometry where straight lines may be parallel at one point and intersect at another. Spacetime curvature means that there is tidal gravity: gravity varies from point to point.

Consider two free falling accelerometers momentarily at rest with respect to each other and at the same altitude high above a planet. Initially being at rest means that their worldlines are parallel, and being in free fall means that they read zero (“straight” worldlines). Due to tidal gravity they will gradually get closer to each other, just as the two longitude lines did. This is curvature of spacetime: the fact that tidal gravity does things to straight worldlines that cannot happen without curvature.

Comment: Minor quibble: I think you mean longitude lines - and they're parallel everywhere on the sphere (two right angle turns and one straight horizontal move takes you from one to the other), they only become nonparallel if you project them onto a planar section (and don't choose a parallelity preserving projection).

Comment: @Dale If you are willing to help me if i tell you where i don't understand and ask you questions about it then i'll proceed. If you are not then i won't ask any questions.

Comment: @gs thanks, I said it right once and wrong once. I have updated to longitude both times as intended. I disagree with that description of parallel since the “horizontal” move is not straight except at the equator. Certainly, since they intersect at the poles it is meaningless to say that they are parallel at the poles

Comment: @josegarcia comments are not really intended for back and forth questions. If you want that type of format then you should go to a discussion forum like physicsforums.com where I also participate

Comment: @Dale we can move to chat here for discussions

Comment: @JoseGarcia I don’t like the chat interface here. I am on a mobile device and it is difficult to use. But here is a blog that goes in more depth https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/understanding-general-relativity-view-gravity-earth/

Comment: @Dale For not going to another website, i'll ask you some short questions. What did you mean by Newtonian worldline? Because as far as i know Newton said an object won't move if there is no force aplied. I also didn't understand what did you mean when you mentioned acceleration. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @JoseGarcia sorry I thought I was clear. This site is not intended for back and forth conversations. They discourage it here in comments and the chat is bad. If you want a discussion instead of a Q&A then you should go to a discussion site not a Q&A site.

Comment: @Dale This is not just a Q&A, the answer might not satisfy the one who asks, so that's why he can ask more and that's the essence of this site. So as you said you don't want to continue then Ok.

Comment: @Dale i'm reading the blog you gave me and it looks good, Do you have more blogs or things about GR?

Comment: @JoseGarcia that is my only blog about GR. I have a few about Bayesian statistics and I collaborated on a couple about SR

Comment: @Dale where we can discuss about GR?

Comment: @JoseGarcia I am active at physicsforums.com for discussions

Answer (score 4):

The bowling ball in a trampoline model of curved spacetime has a lot of problems.  I have looked at it carefully and come to understand that gravity caused by the curvature of spacetime around a planet (or any other mass) works exactly like a low pressure system in the weather.  Why is a leaf attracted to the centre of a low pressure system in the air?  The answer is because the air pressure on the outside side of the leaf is higher than the air pressure on the inside side of the leaf.  It is sucked (or blown) along with the wind into the middle of the Low because of this pressure difference.  Likewise, why does an object fall in gravity?  The answer is because the "pressure" of time above the object is higher than the pressure of time below the object.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc) provides an explanation of this, by implying that the curvature of space leads to the dilation of time, which becomes the pressure difference of which I speak.

So in answer to your basic question, the mass (or energy) causes a warping of space, which in turn leads to dilation of time, which is the attractive cause of gravity.

Comment: That linked video is really good.

Answer (score 2):

Spacetime curvature is well-described by Einstein's equation for gravity, but the math used in it is generally beyond the capabilities of nonprofessionals like me to explain. I invite the professionals here to take a stab at this for you.

The way I visualize this (works for me, may not be technically accurate in all respects) is that large chunks of mass or energy have the effect on spacetime of causing clocks to slow down the closer you get to them. It takes a gigantic concentration of mass or energy to have a detectable effect on clocks in this way which is why gravity is so weak compared to the other forces in nature.

Comment: I would turn around the causation in your last sentence--gravity isn't weak because it takes a huge amount of mass, it takes a huge amount of mass because gravity is weak. (though you could say that the reason we *call* gravity weak is because it takes a huge amount of mass.) The actual reason behind gravity being weak is beyond me, though.

Answer (score 2):

Space is curved if you don't come back to your starting point when you walk around a square. Or equivalently, you wind up at different points if you walk east-then-north vs north-then-east.

The surface of the Earth is curved in this sense. It doesn't show for a small square. But try a really large square. Start on the equator.

- Walk 1/4 of the way around the world to the east. Turn left and walk 1/4 of the way around the world to the north. You are at the north pole.
- Walk 1/4 of the way around the world to the north. Turn right, and walk 1/4 of the way around the world. (OK, it isn't east because coordinates are weird at the north pole.) But you are on the equator.

In GR, a mass causes distortions of distance and time. If you are in orbit, the distance to the center of a star is deeper than you would expect from dividing the circumference traced out by the orbit by $2\pi$. Time runs slower at the surface than in orbit.

Space-time is 4 dimensional, so you get an extra direction you can walk around the block. You can also wait a while.

So trace out this "square" where one side is distance, and the other time. Start at a point above the star.

- Have a person at the top wait a bit, then find the point/time a distance X below him at that time.
- Find the point/time a distance X below the top person right now. Have someone at that bottom point wait a bit.

Time is slower at the bottom. In his travel through time, the bottom person passes through the the point/time the top person picks out. But when he does, he isn't done waiting yet.

Comment: I think this is the clearest way to understand intrinsic curvature, I was going to write something like this. +1.

Answer (score 2):

> I can understand the curvature of a sheet which is 2D but i can't
> understand the 3D curvature of space described in General Relativity.

The usual meaning of the word curvature is what is called extrinsic curvature. Examples are any curved surfaces in the space.

But it is possible to know if a surface is curved without looking at it from the outside. The Earth is an example. We know from basic geometry that the relation of the circunference of a circle and its diameter is the constant $\pi$. But if we make real circles with diameters bigger and bigger in the Earth surface, that relation becomes more and more smaller than $\pi$. That is an example of intrinsic curvature. Theoretically we could know the spherical form of the earth without see it from outside, but only by making carefully measurements on its surface.

The same principle are extended for a space curvature (3D) or spacetime curvature (4D). The difference is that we can't see it from outside, (there is no visual outside for the space as it envelops everything that can be seen), so we must rely only on the intrinsic curvature.

For example, suppose a spaceship approaching radially the sun far from the solar system. And we measure, with one of that laser distance meters, the internal distance from bottom to top of the ship. The measurements of that same object will grow a little, as much we get closer to the sun. That is an indication of the intrinsic space curvature  generated by the solar gravitational field.

Answer (score 1):

Curvature (using the Riemann tensor) is just a mathematical means to account for the unintuitive weirdness that happens to an object when you move (parallel transport) the object around a closed path in space-time.  Suppose you move an object (ie: a vector $V$) around 2 sides of a square path resulting in a vector $V_1$.  You are very careful to only translate the vector and not do any other transformation (like rotating or boosting) to it.  Then you move $V$ around the other 2 sides of the square path resulting in $V_2$, again being careful to only translate it.  If space has zero curvature (ie: Riemann tensor$=0$), you will find $V_1=V_2$.

If space-time has a constant curvature (eg: cosmological constant $\Lambda$) and your square path was $\delta x \ \delta y$ , you will experimentally find $V_1=Rotation_Z(\Lambda \ \delta x \ \delta y )V_2$. If your square path was $\delta x \ \delta ct$ , you will find $V_1=Boost_X(\Lambda \ \delta x \ \delta ct )V_2$.  The cosmological constant is very small so $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ must be very large for you to see a noticeable rotation angle $\theta_z=\Lambda \ \delta x \ \delta y$ or Lorentz boost parameter $\lambda_x=\Lambda \ \delta x \ \delta ct$, so you don't normally experience this and might think it weird when you see it.

The curvature near big masses (according to Einstein's field equations) is much larger than $\Lambda$ and varies in space-time. We regularly see its effect in Newtonian gravity.

You are also familiar with the effect of curvature in the 2d case of moving a vector around a closed path on the surface of a sphere.  Even though you were very careful to always move the vector parallel to itself (ie: no rotation). The final vector will be rotated wrt the initial vector.