# Is space build of smaller space-particles?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, discrete, aether

In atomic physics one of the most decisive proves that the objects are build of atoms is that they can be deformed and twisted. So is it not logical to believe that space itself is also build of something smaller - some "atoms" of space, which could explain that it can bend (in presence of mass) and can twist (by the rotation of Earth - which has been measured some time ago). Are there theories trying to explain this facts by some granular "atomic" structure of space?

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer this in parts.

- It is too much of a leap to say matter is stretchy and bendable. Matter is made of atoms. Space is stretchy and bendable. Space must be made of atoms too. There could be other ways of being stretchy and bendable.
- Space can curve, but it is a different thing from the stretchiness of matter.
- We don't know what space is like on the tiniest scales. We can't say if space has a granular structure or not.

---

Part of the reason that matter is stretchy comes from it being made of atoms. The atoms are connected together with atomic bonds, and the bonds are stretchy and bendable to a degree.

But that isn't the only way to imagine the cause of an object being stretchable. People can model how objects deform by supposing that it is made of little cubical blocks, and each block is a continuous substance that is rubbery to a degree. It gives good answers. So stretchability by itself isn't proof of having an atomic nature.

There are other properties of matter that lead to the conclusion it is made of atoms. For example if you throw particles or X-rays at it, the way they scatter is consistent with little atoms and space between. It is not consistent with a uniform continuous substance.

Physicists have imagined similar tests that might tell us about the nature of space. But they require particle accelerators that would be enormously more powerful than anything we will ever be able to build.

---

Matter deforms under the action of forces. You can stretch a spring by pulling on the ends. You can't do that to space. The curvature of space means something else.

First, you have to add time to the mix. Spacetime can be curved. This is the cause of gravity. It is often presented as the Earth sitting on a rubber sheet and bending it. The moon rolls around the dent, orbiting the earth. This does make it seem like space is a "fabric", as if it was made of rubber.

This model is seriously misleading. Here is a much better version of it. [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc). It still uses the words "fabric of space-time", but do not take it literally.

The curvature of space-time refers to distances and times being different that you would expect near massive objects.

You can orbit around a star and measure the time it takes to orbit. A person on the planet would measure a shorter time for your orbit. His clock runs slower.

Likewise you can measure the distance you travel. If you divide that by $\pi$, you would expect to get the distance you would need to travel across the diameter of the orbit. A person making that journey would find that the distance to the center of the star is deeper than it would be in flat space-time.

These differences in the nature of space and time near massive objects are the cause of gravity. It is not gravity somehow pulling on space and time that causes these changes.

Here is more on it. [Can someone really explain the curvature of Spacetime?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/684990/37364)

---

Here is a video about the Planck length, the smallest length that current physics can handle. [Is the Planck length really the smallest?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzB2R_qiC28)

At scales smaller than this, we don't have working theories. We won't really know how physics works at such scales until we figure out a quantum theory of gravity. Here is a video that discusses why. [Quantum Gravity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbPWYjnQIO8).

People are working toward that. There are various candidate theories such as supersymmetry and loop quantum gravity. They haven't been fully worked out, and certainly haven't been checked out to see which, if any, are right.

[Loop Quantum Gravity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMpkFde3euA) does contain the idea that there is a smallest size. But doesn't say that space behaves like atoms. We don't know if it correctly describes the universe. So far, there is no evidence to confirm it.

Comment: @annav - Thank you. I have made some corrections.

Comment: The question is in the sense that we accept atoms from the facts of twisteness and deformation of the objects but do not consider this  true for space itself.

Comment: Space is a concept that we use to help organize things. It is not a "thing" in itself.

Comment: How it is possible for something to twist and bend but not to have a discontinuous structure? Why a double measure is used? How can it bend and not be a thing in itself.

Comment: @mmesser314 You try to deliver a good answer. I appreciate it. But I don't agree that we can not stretch space. The forces on the matter are fields acting on other 1/2 spin fields in the end. Same way gravitation field can be viewed to interact with the fabric of space and bend and stretch it.